# Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined - Google Maps - React JS

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'>
    </div>
    <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

myComponent.js

```
const google = Window.google;
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

when running the code I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined
```

but when I

```
console.log(window)
```

I can see google inside window and maps inside google...

What could be the issue? I'm guessing something about loading, but not sure how to fix it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: function Geoc() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}
export default class MapComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const google = window.google;
    console.log(window);
    Geoc();
  }

  render() {
    return ();
  }
}

Comment: The solution was to include the script loading the api inside the <head> tags

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
const google =window.google;
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

Or use this:

```
geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();
```